# Find the generating function of the sequence $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots)$ where $a_n = n2^n$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am tasked to find the generating function of the sequence $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots)$ where $a_n = n2^n$

Here is how I approached it:
First, I wrote out the first few terms of the sequence, $(0, 2, 8, 24, 64)$.

Then, using the definition of a generating function, set up this summation:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{}n2^{n}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{}n(2x)^{n}$$

However, I am stuck here. I am not sure if this is the right start, but it seems promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{}n(x)^{n-1}$. Then integrate it.

$\int f(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^{}(x)^{n}=\frac{x}{1-x}$.

$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

$\frac{2x}{(1-2x)^2}=2xf(2x)= \sum_{n=0}^{}n(2x)^{n}$.